What criteria were used for the Qualification for the Judo 2004 Summer Olympics and how did the final ranking of the Judokas look like?
To participate at the Olympic Games the Judokas have to qualify by achieving results at tournaments. I am looking for a list of tournaments which were used for the qualification for the 2004 Summer Olympics in Judo.
I found:

List of how the athletes finally qualified
List of PJU athletes;
List of PJU tournaments
All qualifying tournaments


First, you can have a list of participants on the official IJF homepage as well. Also, generally, it is about collecting a certain threshold of points to qualify. If more than one player per weight class and NOC qualifies, the national federation decides who's going. In Germany, it's the head coach. The decision may not reflect the (higher) ranking of players not chosen.

"First, you can have a list of participants on the official IJF homepage as well" -
Where is a list of participants of the qualification tournaments? Link Please.

I wrote "list of participants" in reference to a former version where you linked to a different site for those who finally participated in the games. Those, you can find here on an official IJF site. Sadly, most official sites are not hosting content that is 20+ years old, so you will be hard-pressed to find what you are looking for.

The list of tournaments can be found on this archived page of the Australian Judo Union:
1.  2003 World Championship 
    The top placed 6 athletes in each weight category for both men and women will qualify their NOC a qualification place in the corresponding weight category.
        6 places x 7 categories x 2 (men + women)   **Total 84 athletes**
2.  Continental Qualification Systems
    266 athletes will be qualified through continental qualification systems, in accordance with the distribution specified in the table above. The specific qualification system for each continent is attached following the general judo text.   
        **Total 266 athletes**
3.  Host nation 
    The host nation will be directly qualified in each weight category. If athletes of the host nation qualify through the world championships or through the continental qualification system, the corresponding place will be reallocated within the continental qualification system for Europe.
        7 places for men and 7 places for women         **Total 14 places**
4.  Tripartite Commission (IOC-ANOC-IJF) Invitation places
    15 Tripartite Commission Invitation places will be made available for eligible nations The deadline for NOCs to submit their requests for Tripartite Commission Invitation places is 15 November 2003. The Tripartite Commission will confirm, in writing, a preliminary allocation of Invitation places to the NOCs by 31 January 2004. The allocation of remaining Invitation places will be confirmed, in writing, to the NOCs in June 2004.
        **Total 15 places**
5. Final qualification places
7 places will be allocated in May 2004 to NOCs not otherwise qualified, based on results achieved during the 2003 World Championships.          
        **Total 7 places**

The Continental Qualification Systems varies widely between continents. for the OJU there are three tournaments listed and for the EJU there are more then 20.

The list of how the Judokas qualified can be found on the website of the IJF (page 1-10):

INV - Invitation
UQS - Union Qualification System
WCH - World Championships

